# How to determine if View is instance of PhoneWindow$DecorView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a method which receives list of Views, views could be instances of Linear Layout, Relative Layout, ImageView etc.  I want to remove all Layout , PhoneDecor Views.

When I print the list of views, DecorView looks like as follows

```
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f115dc3 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-1440,2560
```

I am planning to have method like this

```
public List<View> filterViews(List<View> inputViews)
{
   //if view instanceOf LinearLayout or RelativeLayout  -- remove 
}
```

How can I check if view is instance of the type -- PhoneWindow$DecorView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare your class `getName()` with "`com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.DecorView`"

$ means `DecorView` is an inner class of the `PhoneWindow` class.

Comment: right, I was unsure how to check inner class, thanks I will try this